# Background Inside a Background

Tags: html, css, background

I have been trynig to put a background inside a background on my website. I was able to put the background color that I wanted with this code:

```
<body bgcolor="#F5F2D4">
<div class="Gallery">
<h1> Gallery </h1>
</div>
</body>
```

After, in  CSS I did the following

```
.Gallery h1 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Century Gothic', CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
font-size: 55px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 26.3999996185303px;
background-color: White;
}
```

The background would look something like this (B=Beige, W=White:

```
-------------------------
|BB|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|BB|
|BB|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|BB|
|BB|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|BB|
|BB|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|BB|
|BB|WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW|BB|
-------------------------
```

This made the colors that I wanted in the background, but it is not scaled. It only has a few pixels of difference from the border of the browser until the White starts, is there any way to make the distance increase?

Also, is there any way to make the White Background scroll all the way down?

Thank you very much.

Comment: show what you have tried so far. Some css code will be helpful.

Comment: Um. You just put backgrounds on different elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `html`, `body` and `.gallery` all a `height: 100%` to make the `.gallery` take up the entire height of the screen.

If you want the `.gallery` to have a fixed width (as in the example below) give it a `width` and add `margin: 0 auto` to have it center itself horizontally in the screen. If you don't want it to have a fixed width add a `padding: 0 100px` on the `body` if you want to have 100 pixels from the left and right side of the `.gallery` to be beige.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: beige;
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery {
  background-color: white;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That image **isn't made up of a single background**: it's made up of multiple elements which have **different** backgrounds:

```
+-----------------------+
|BB|YYYYYYYYY|NNNNNNN|BB|
|BB|YYYYYYYYY|NNNNNNN|BB|
|BB|YYYYYYYYY|NNNNNNN|BB|
|BB|YYYYYYYYY|NNNNNNN|BB|
|BB|YYYYYYYYY|NNNNNNN|BB|
+-----------------------+
```

Where the letters represent certain coloured/different backgrounds.

For example, below I've used three elements:

```css
.all {
  min-height: 100vh;
  height:500px;
    background-color: green;
  width: 100%;

  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.left {
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 5%;
}
.right {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 45%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="all">

  <div class="left">i will always be on left. Think of me like a column!</div>
  <div class="right">i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i
    will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i
    will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!i will always be on right. Think of me like a column!!!!!!!!!!!!!</div>
</div>
```

**Note** I've used background-colors, but alternatively you can use images/etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the code works just fine, but it leaves a little Red line in the middle of the two Blue and Green sections, is there a way to not have it?

Comment: add a left margin of -1% to your right element (**edited answer**)